# Confluent kafka jdbc connect query mode

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent kafka connect jdbc source to push records from mysql table to my kafka topic, but it seems the date column is getting converted to epoch time.

This is my config :

```
{
    "name": "mysql-source-test", 
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
            "tasks.max": "5",
            "name": "mysql-source-test",
            "connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brint?user=abc&password=xyz",
            "topic.prefix":"mysql-source-test",
            "poll.interval.ms":"100000000",
            "query":"select updated_on from temp;",
            "mode":"timestamp",
            "batch.max.rows":"10"
    }
}
```

Output in kafka topic :

```
{"updated_on":1531323874000}
```

I also tried from_unixtime() in the query like "select from_unixtime(updated_on) from temp", but that's not working.

Is there a way push it to kafka in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any way to do it.

So I changed the query.

Query : `select CAST(date_format(updated_on, \"%b %d, %Y %r\") as CHAR(50)) from temp;`

And this worked.